# изменить часть данных в столбце с % на десятичную дробь

Tags: python

есть столбец с данными, в котором часть представлена в виде десятичной дроби, часть число со знаком %. Необходимо привести все данные к виду десятичной дроби, то есть удалить знак % и разделить на 10. Какой код написать? пробовала через функцию, но что-то похоже делаю неверно
[image: данные]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: у меня есть рейтинг фильмов data['ratings'] в котором данные смешанные - и % и десятичные дроби. надо привести все к одному виду

Comment: Данные должны быть в воспроизводимом (текстовом) виде, а не скриншотом.

Answer (score 0):

если это простой список, то сделать можно так:

```
a = ['1.3', '5.6', '90%', '2.4']

res = [str(int(x.rstrip('%'))/10) if '%' in x else x for x in a]
print(res)
```

При этом все значения в списке останутся строковыми.

> ['1.3', '5.6', '9.0', '2.4']

Либо так:

```
res = [int(x.rstrip('%'))/10 if '%' in x else float(x) for x in a]
print(res)
```

Теперь все значения станут вещественными числами:

> [1.3, 5.6, 9.0, 2.4]

Если это столбец датафрейма

```
  rating
0    1.3
1    5.6
2    90%
3    2.4
```

то:

```
df = df.where(~df["rating"].str.contains("%"), df["rating"]
              .str.strip("%").astype(float)/10, axis=0)
```

получите столбец типа object:

```
  rating
0    1.3
1    5.6
2    9.0
3    2.4
```